# VS Code JavaScript IntelliSense suggestion problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I have problem with *Visual Studio Code* suggestion and *IntelliSense*. You can see in the images that it doesn't suggest me, but it suggests the instructor the same thing. And as you can see, there is a `%33` in image; is it an extension or settings that is causing this behaviour?

### Instructor's Screen

[image]

### My Screen

[image]

Comment: Please replace the images with a text-based [mcve]

Comment: most likely an extension, you'd be better off asking your instructor about his environment configuration

Comment: Are you sure the language code for each is the same? Maybe one is JSX and the other is JS?

Comment: @evolutionxbox hi. Yes it's same both JS. i googled for hours but i couldnt find anything

Comment: @PatrickBarr  Unfortunately I cant contact with instructor

Comment: I get no suggestions either when using the code in the lower screenshot.

Comment: In VSCode it'll be an extension.